# How Do I insert Date and Time into SQL Server database in certain format?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am using Windows forms in C#.

I am trying to fill a table in a SQL Server database which contains `DateTime` column.

Now when my PC's clock format is `dd-MM-yyyy` and when I try to insert the data with the following query, I get an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Code:

```
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN11-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
 cn.Open();

 SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Orders (Order_number, Phone, DateTime, address ) values ('" 
                  + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "', '"+  DateTime.Now  +"' ,'" 
                  + textBox3.Text + "')");

 cm.Connection = cn;
 cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cn.Close();
```

But when I change my PC's clock format to `yyyy-MM-dd` it works fine. It seems that SQL Server only accepts `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

My question is : how can I insert `DateTime` into SQL Server column according to my PC's clock format (`dd-MM-yyyy`)?

Thank you

Comment: Pass it in universal format which is YYYY-MM-DD. You can format the date using CulturalInfo according to this topic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: if you really want that then in sql server data type will be varchar and then convert date to your desired format and also to string and then insert that.

Comment: Please note that `DateTime` does not have a format.  That applies to both the .Net data type and the SQL column type.  Now when you construct a SQL string you end up formatting the `DateTime` to a string representation and then the DB has to parse that based on some expected format and that's the issue here.  And as some answers mention the solution is to use parameters to avoid having to worry about formatting at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of concatenating your sql command text, use parameterized query.

It will not only protects you from sql injection, but also it uses strongly typed parameters (for example, parameter should has type of `SqlDbType.DateTime` to pass datetime values), thus problem will gone.

```
var cm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Orders (Order_number, Phone, DateTime) values (@OrderNumber, @Phone, @DateTime)");
cm.Parameters.Add("@OrderNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cm.Parameters["@OrderNumber"].Value = textBox1.Text;
cm.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cm.Parameters["@phone"].Value = textBox2.Text;
cm.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cm.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am new to SQL . so I understand from your code that you insert the dateTime into the column with the format that the SQL server wants, Am I right? and last question please: is it possible for the  dateTime  column to contain dd-MM-yyyy format as my PC does? because even with your code the column still have yyyy-MM-dd formate . thank you

Comment: @naouf you can't change format in which sql server stores datetime values. And this is totally internal format, it has nothing common with `dd-MM-yyyy` or `yyyy-MM-dd` which is only *visual representations* of data. Just pass C# `DateTime` object as value of sql cpmmand parameter and stop worrying about formats. :)